# Get fee amount using PayPal Adaptive Payments API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-nvp

I am beating my head against the wall with this one.  I am setting up a payment using the PayPal Adaptive Payments API, where one of my platform's users receives a payment from their customer.  I need to be able to see the *amount* of the PayPal fee related to that transaction.

I'm familiar with and have tried using the [PaymentDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/) API operation, but unfortunately, the only quasi-relevant information that method (and the IPN) returns is `fees_payer` (*who* paid the fees), not the amount of the fee.

I've also looked into the [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) operation, but that appears to be only for Express Checkout and Website Payments Pro APIs, according to [this document.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_transaction/)

Any ideas how I can determine the *fee amount* on these transactions?

Answer (score 0):

With Adaptive Payments the IPNNotificationURL specified in the Pay request would be an app specific IPN that won't provide much info about that payment itself.

If you setup IPN in the receiver account profile, then an additional IPN would be triggered that would be transaction specific and would include the fee.